# Как можно изменить данные проходящие через адаптер?

Tags: java, android, listview

С помощью `SimpleCursorAdapter` достаю из базы данных числа из столбца, передаю их в `TextView` для отображения, хотелось бы сделать промежуточное изменение этих чисел, что бы проверять, если в ячейке число есть, то записывать в `textview` не само число а число + "текст".Мне бы хоть понять в какую сторону копать.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView lv;
    DataBase db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        db = new DataBase(this);
        db.open();

        cursor = db.getAllData();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] {db.COLUMN_ODOMETER};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.odometer};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_lv_adapter, 
              cursor, from, to);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.History);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

пытался делать что то вроде указания `db.COLUMN_ODOMETER + "text"` но это бред какой то)

Comment: Вы пробовали написать свой адаптер, расширив `SimpleCursorAdapter`? вам надо переопределить метод `getView()`

Comment: в адаптер вы сетите курсор, вот перед этим и меняйте данные в курсоре как вам надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно создать наследника от `SimpleCursorAdapter`, перекрыть у него метод `bindView`, и в нем записывать в `textview` что душе угодно.

Соответственно, потом экземпляр этого вашего класса и использовать как адаптер для списка.